# SVG is not scaling when adding sizing to it with CSS

Tags: svg

I'm trying to resize an svg element using css by setting `width` and `height` to a smaller value than the inline one, but it is not scaling, the end result is an empty square, the thing is that the `<svg>` element itself changes sizes, but the `<path>`'s inside it do not, this is shown by inspecting them in the browser's devtools.

The svg element is imported as a `react` component using SVGR, the styling is set using `styled-components`.

Before writing this post I read some possible solutions online, none worked (removing inline width and height, adding viewbox to same values as width and height etc...), any clue?

```
<svg width="512" height="512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <title/>

 <g>
  <title>background</title>
  <rect fill="none" id="canvas_background" height="402" width="582" y="-1" x="-1"/>
 </g>
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <path id="svg_1" fill="#fff133" d="m276.6,127.6a148.4,148.4 0 0 0 -114.46,242.86a148.49,148.49 0 0 0 164.33,16.54a150.66,150.66 0 0 1 -15.94,-16.51a148.38,148.38 0 0 1 9.79,-236.29a148.18,148.18 0 0 0 -43.72,-6.6z"/>
  <path id="svg_2" stroke-width="20" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="#455a64" fill="none" d="m116.5,207c-0.37,1.05 -0.73,2.11 -1.07,3.17"/>
  <path id="svg_3" stroke-width="20" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="#455a64" fill="none" d="m109.77,234.43a148.43,148.43 0 0 0 221,150.11a148.44,148.44 0 0 1 0,-257.08a148.46,148.46 0 0 0 -204,56.62"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Use a viewBox attribute like `<svg viewBox="0 0 512 512" ` and no width and height Now  you can resize it in css for example svg{width:256px;}

Comment: thanks a lot, this worked, although i tried it before and i just realised that i was making a mistake with the casing viewbox -> viewBox